# How can I make a cocos2d game only support iPod4 /iPhone4 and later

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone

My game was rejected, because it crashes in iPad, but I don't want the game to support iPad. I did not even upload any screen-shoot to iTunes Connect. How can I do this?

Comment: It didn't ask you to specify supported devices when you submitted the app?

Comment: Not found,but Project -> Build Settings -> Targeted Device Family is set to iPhoen, not iPhone/iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. All apps will be able to run on iPads, even those set to iPhone-only. They just won't use the full screen size / pixel density.

iPhone-only apps run in the 1x/2x compatibility modes on iPad where content is optionally scaled up.

You should try to confirm the crash on iPad simulator or (better) an actual iPad device.